# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource change problem1

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in the first column that is bind whith a `List<MyClass>` and a `DisplayMember="name"` (I dont set the valeumember because i want to get myclass when I accesse to value). The second column is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` too. It will be bound to some `List<String>` based on the first `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` selectedValue.

All this work just fine, the problem starts when I change the first `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource`. When I add a new Myclass to the datasource it works, but if I select the class I will get an error:

> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

Code:

```
//Set columns to Datagridview  
DataGridViewImageColumn btnEdit = new DataGridViewImageColumn();  
Image gear = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.gear;  
btnEdit.Image = gear;  
datagridview.Columns.Add(btnEdit);  

//Table  
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbTable = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();  
cbTable.HeaderText = "Table";  
cbTable.Name = "Table";  
cbTable.DisplayMember = "NameToShow";  
//tableDataSource = cbTable.DataSource;  
//cbTable.DataSource = moduleClone.SqlQuery.Tables;  
datagridview.Columns.Add(cbTable);  

//...  
//...  
//...  

//Load data  
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)datagridview.Columns[1]).DataSource = (List<Table>)moduleClone.SqlQuery.Tables;  
//Work just fine  

//...  
//...  
//...  

//Now if i reload de data  
datagridview.Rows.Clear();  
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)datagridview.Columns[1]).DataSource = (List<Table>)moduleClone.SqlQuery.Tables;  
//This give me one message box with the exception several times when drawing the gridview.
```

Comment: `but if I select the class I will get an error` what you mean by this? Can you try to make it clear?

Comment: Hi @Sami, When i select the item in the combox. That wasnt to clear.. :S

HaemEternal I´m new in this forum and in every forum to be honest, I try to put some code but i can not get it configured **:(** I try to do to like the help exemple but doesn't work and the number of charaters is too low to.. There are some right way ti do it that i'm missing ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that works for me.
Instead use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource`, I directly change `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items`. Has a probleme because you cant change `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items` if `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource` is set. So I define `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = null` before edit `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Itens`.

Code:

```
//Set columns to Datagridview  
DataGridViewImageColumn btnEdit = new DataGridViewImageColumn();  
Image gear = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.gear;  
btnEdit.Image = gear;  
datagridview.Columns.Add(btnEdit);  

//Table  
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbTable = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();  
cbTable.HeaderText = "Table";  
cbTable.Name = "Table";  
cbTable.DisplayMember = "NameToShow";  
datagridview.Columns.Add(cbTable);  

//...  
//...  
//...  

//Load data  
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)datagridview.Columns[1]).Itens = (List<Table>)moduleClone.SqlQuery.Tables;  
//Work just fine  

//...  
//...  
//...  

//Now I reload de data  
datagridview.Rows.Clear();
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)datagridview.Columns[1]).DataSource = null; 
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)datagridview.Columns[1]).Items.clear();
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)datagridview.Columns[1]).Items= (List<Table>)moduleClone.SqlQuery.Tables;
```